# Find out PNG transparent background color on Linux

Tags: command-line, png

It appears that PNG files contain background color information for transparent pixels. This sometimes becomes noticeable when using that image as a texture with wrong settings.

How to find out in Linux (ideally command line) what the color of the transparent pixels in a PNG file is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background color is conveyed via the PNG "bKGD" chunk.

From the command line, you can use "pngcheck -v".  Download and install  pngcheck from

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html

then type

```
pngcheck -v file.png
```

If a bKGD chunk is present in the PNG file, pngcheck's output will include something like this:

> chunk bKGD at offset 0x000a0, length 6
>    red = 0x00e0, green = 0x00e0, blue = 0x0080

You probably already have ImageMagick (version 6.6.9 or later), so you could also obtain bKGD chunk information, along with a lot of other stuff, by typing

```
identify -verbose file.png
```

and look for

> Background color: srgba(224,224,128,1)
>
> png:bKGD: chunk was found (see Background color, above)

If only "Background color" appears but not "png:bKGD:...", then identify is reporting ImageMagick's default background color and no bKGD chunk is present in the PNG file.

Comment: Thanks! identify is more readable, more widely available and pngcheck doesn't seem to show that info for grayscale images: http://codepad.org/2yquVHrc

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the image being grayscale, just that it lacks a bKGD chunk (which is an optional chunk!).  ImageMagick will show a background color because ImageMagick assumes a default background color if there is none in the PNG file.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The PNG specification ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11transinfo)) describes the tRNS chunk where transparency information is stored.

The software library [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) can read and write PNG files, including the transparency information.  Specifically, look up the following function:

```
png_get_tRNS(png_ptr, info_ptr, &trans_alpha, &num_trans, &trans_color)
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can't program on that level, which is why I chose superuser and not stackoverflow http://superuser.com/help/on-topic